# R code optimizing for rep function

Tags: r, statistics, analytics

I'm working with data from an income/expense per home poll.
The 9,002 observations from the sample data base represent 3,155,937 homes through an expansion factor like this.

```
Homeid    Income    Factor
001       23456     678
002       42578     1073
..        ..        ..
9002      62333     987
```

I'm trying to get an exact summary of the total income per decile by expanding each income value times its factor which will give as result a 3,155,937 ovservations vector and then I'm using a 'for' loop to asign each value the Decile it belongs to.

```
Three <- Nal %>% select(income,factor) 
Five <- data.frame(income=rep(Three$income,Three$factor))
for(i in 1:31559379){if(i<=3155937){Five$Decil[i]=1}
else{if(i<=6311874){Five$Decil[i]=2}
else{if(i<=9467811){Five$Decil[i]=3}
else{if(i<=12623748){Five$Decil[i]=4}
else{if(i<=15779685){Five$Decil[i]=5}
else{if(i<=18935622){Five$Decil[i]=6}
else{if(i<=22091559){Five$Decil[i]=7}
else{if(i<=25247496){Five$Decil[i]=8}
else{if(i<=28403433){Five$Decil[i]=9}
else{Five$Decil[i]=10}
}}}}}}}}}
for(i in 1:10){Two=filter(Five,Decil==i);
TotDecil$inctot[i]=sum(Two$income)}
rm(Five);rm(Three);rm(Two);gc()
```

I want to know if you can help me optimize this code; it has taken hours and still haven't finished.

Comment: Try looking at the help for `cut`, `findInterval`, `quantile` and other functions linked from there

Comment: thanks a lot! the `ntile` function worked better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ntile` function from the `dplyr` package worked better:

```
Three <- Nal %>% select(income,factor) 
Five <- data.frame(income=rep(Three$income,Three$factor))

Cinco$Decil <- ntile(Cinco$ing_cor,10)
# ^ This line works instead of that 'for' loop & it only takes seconds to run
```

Comment: it would be well worth pointing out that you're using `dplyr` here ... perhaps obvious from `%>%`, but I had to look up the `ntile` function.